# Tracking an object with OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I am trying to implement tracking of a **single object** with OpenCV as a part of a robot, that tracks an object which is marked by a rectangular region in a frame. Based on that template defined in a frame, the robot must chase that object. The object cannot be of a single color and also the orientation of the object changes. The video captured by the robot is processed by a laptop and commands for the movement is send to the robot as a result of processing.

I am pretty new to OpenCV. After reading something about motion tracking, i found optical flow with Lucas-Kanade Method suits for this purpose by dynamically updating the template.

Is this method enough for my requirements? 
Is it possible to achieve realtime processing using this method ?
I also want to know whether any other method(s) best suits my purpose ?

Please correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Tracking is a widely researched topic and there is no standard (and no generally robust) solution. Fairly robust tracking code are written for years mostly by PhD students.

If you are allowed to use someone else's code, type in youtube: [Predator: Camera That Learns](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=predator+tracking&oq=predator+tracking&gs_l=youtube.3..0l10.427.1925.0.2206.9.6.0.0.0.0.464.2394.2-1j1j4.6.0...0.0...1ac.1.v-1EEykeVUc). It is a fairly generic fast tracking algorithm (under the hood it is a **feature-based** advanced Haar-like tree/cascade classifier). There, in the video you can find references to research papers and if you google-up the inventor guy Zdanek's old university homepage you can download and use his code.

If you have to do your own code, you resort to some very simple system. If your tracked object does not change too much and does not move violently, I would recommend using **template matching**. Once the detection differs some from the original template, you can update your template with a recent detection. This causes a **drift**. If the drift is too much, you can go back to the original template.

Note however: there is not much to expect from tinkering at tracking... Lucas-Kanade is only robust in the research papers. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The place I'd start is [YouTube](http://youtube.com), look at what other researchers have done thus far and see if their research papers is posted online. Other keywords you may google is Voila Jones classifier (face recognition), AdaBoost based object classifier, Active Appearance Model and a ton of new research papers (definitely out of my league).

You can check out something I wrote in [flash](http://blue.netnation.com/~ftibet/projects/face/face.html) back in the early 2009. Need webcam and flash on your browser, uses openCV as backend.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the question is bit late but may help for future references.

I developed a project for learning tracking of an object using OpenCV C++ lib. The link to my project is https://bitbucket.org/iankits/opencv_development/. The wiki page of the project gives you all details of the problem statement and various pointers for learning tracking of the object.

My main solution link is [HERE](https://bitbucket.org/iankits/opencv_development/src/23fc9e829d14e2bf4469c77ae92b6f98b32c328c/template_tracking_project_solution?at=master). I wanted to track a turtle in the video. For this, I used **template matching** method of openCV library.

> matchTemplate( frame, templ, result, match_method );

I selected the turtle from a frame of the video and saved as a *.png file. Then I used that png file as a template to match with every frame of the video. It worked great for my purpose. But I should admit that it is not a great solution. Incase, you are using this for robot vision, i would recommend you to use "**Haartraining**" which is a machine learning technique given in OpenCV. You can also have a look into my try [HERE](https://bitbucket.org/iankits/opencv_development/src/23fc9e829d14e2bf4469c77ae92b6f98b32c328c/haartraining_turtle?at=master).

Hope this may help.